# WebSockets (STOMP) streaming audio from back-end Spring Boot to front-end Vuejs

Tags: spring-boot, rest, audio-streaming, spring-websocket, vuejs3

I'm developing an audio streaming platform like Spotify for a school project. I used Vuejs for the front-end application and implemented an audio player. This is working.

Now I need a way to send audio files from a back-end to my front-end. I now have a micro service called streaming service using Spring Boot and used WebSocktets (STOMP) to make a connection with the front-end. But I see it's mostly used for chat applications or conference call applications..

I read it is heavy to send audio files via REST, because of making connections repeatedly. Which way is the most efficient way to implement this?

Please be specific in your answer since I'm not a advanced developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read it is heavy to send audio files via REST, because of making connections repeatedly.

Not really.  For something like Spotify, a normal HTTP Progressive stream is sufficient.  In this case only one TCP connection is typically made, over which a small handful of ranged HTTP requests will go over.

Web Sockets are only appropriate for cases where you need a bidirectional data flow.  In this case, you just have requests and responses, which a normal HTTP request is suitable for.

Usage of regular HTTP also means you can utilize standard CDNs.